# Typescript: How to access element of array object?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I've written a array for store language options.

```
public languageOptions:Array<Object> = [
    {
    name: 'English',
    value: 'en'
    },
    {
    name: 'France',
    value: "fr"
    }
];
```

And I want to set **English** as default language. I did it in following way,

```
private static readonly DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: string = 'en';
```

But I want to set '**en**' value directly from the object array like this,

```
private static readonly DEFAULT_LANGUAGE: string = languageOptions[0].value;
```

But when I write that, it gives following error

> [ts] Cannot find name 'languageOptions'

Can someone please help me to solve this problem. Please advice how to access 'en' from array object. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot access an instance property like `languageOptions` from a static method--it doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you want `languageOptions` to be status too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **`this`**

```
export class App {
 languageOptions = [
    {
    name: 'English',
    value: 'en'
    },
    {
    name: 'France',
    value: "fr"
    }
];
 private readonly DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = this.languageOptions[0].value;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/wFQGkMTxqoasv8h4lNPk)**

Comment: then it returns, "[ts] Property 'languageOptions' does not exist on type 'typeof AppComponent'." error

Comment: did you check the demo

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an instance member (aka non static, `languageOptions` in your case) from a static member initialization (for `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE`).

Also do not type you array as `Array<object>`, this will not let the compiler do inference and help you out after. Just use :

```
public static languageOptions = [
    {
    name: 'English',
    value: 'en'
    },
    {
    name: 'France',
    value: "fr"
    }
];
```